# Why does theBufferedImage output look different than on screen in the JFrame window on Linux platform?

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe, bufferedimage

I am working on one project that requires to capture image data of on-screen GUI (e.g. JFrame). Somehow, my application is working for windows and Mac OS, but for Linux it's not giving same Image output as on-screen GUI.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class jframeExample {

public static BufferedImage getImageData(
        Component component) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            component.getWidth(),
            component.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    component.printAll( image.createGraphics() );
    return image;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final JFrame f = new JFrame("JFrame Border");
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.setLocation(500,300);
            f.setSize(560, 420);
            f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            JMenuItem screenshot =
                    new JMenuItem("TakeSnapshot");
            screenshot.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            BufferedImage imageOutput = getImageData(f);
                            try {
                                // write the image as a PNG
                                ImageIO.write(
                                        imageOutput,
                                        "png",
                                        new File("CapturedImage.png"));
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } );
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menu.add(screenshot);
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.add(menu);
            f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
 }
}
```

Above code will give GUI with Menu option to capture it as an image output. You can see on-screen GUI and image output of it as attached files.Generated image is little different than on-screen GUI. See left/right edge of JFrame border, it overlap with contentPane blue color.

How to get exact same image as on-screen GUI OR tweak left/right border so that it don't overlap with contentPane area? I tried couple of options using LookAndFeel class but not getting any success yet. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

[On-Screen GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SyK4.png)
[CapturedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZyh.png)

Comment: This issue has been reported as a bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8167261

Answer (score 1):

Swing doesn't paint the entire frame. The frame is a widget of the OS.

Try using [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/).

It will use the `Robot` class to take an image when a frame is specified as the component. Otherwise is will use the Swing painting.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Fix

Try changing...

```
BufferedImage imageOutput = getImageData(f);
```

to

```
BufferedImage imageOutput = getImageData(f.getContentPane());
```

This might work on Linux too (I can't test it at the moment) and would be an easy fix to your problem.

### Solution

Alternatively you can use the `Robot` class. `Robot` has a more compatible screen capture capability, but this means serious alterations to your code. You can find the code at the very bottom of my answer. Let me explain the reasons for all the changes...

1. `Robot` is the class needed to perform screen captures. It can capture either the full desktop or a part of the screen. In this case, we will let it capture the blue part of your application by finding out the respective XY coordinates on the desktop. `Robot` needs to be static in this case because you are trying to access it through the `main()` method. Therefore the `Robot` variable needs to be outside of the `main()` method so that the `JMenuItem`'s `ActionListener` can access it.
2. If you perform the screen capture through the menu, the menu will appear in the screen capture because you haven't given the menu time to disappear. As a result, a delay needs to be added. Simultaneously, this delay needs to occur in a separate thread, otherwise your menu will just freeze... The way I created the new thread is called a Lambda expression. It's just an easy way to easily create a new thread that starts immediately, that's all. It works like this: `new Thread(() -> { /* Do something */ }.start();`
3. Next is to find the coordinates of the blue part of the screen. This is a simple `getLocationOnScreen()` on the context pane of the frame (or which-ever component you wish to capture).
4. Now the screen capture can be created by `Robot` and saved to file using your previous code.

That's all! If you have any questions just place a comment and I'll check back later.

### Code

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class jframeExample {

public static BufferedImage getImageData(
        Component component) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            component.getWidth(),
            component.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    component.printAll( image.createGraphics() );
    return image;
}

static Robot robot = null;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(robot == null) robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            final JFrame f = new JFrame("JFrame Border");
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.setLocation(500,300);
            f.setSize(560, 420);
            f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);


            JMenuItem screenshot =
                    new JMenuItem("TakeSnapshot");
            screenshot.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            new Thread(() -> {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                int screenshotX = f.getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen().x;
                                int screenshotY = f.getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen().y;
                                int screenshotWidth = f.getContentPane().getWidth();
                                int screenshotHeight = f.getContentPane().getHeight();
                                BufferedImage imageOutput = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(screenshotX, screenshotY, screenshotWidth, screenshotHeight));
                                try {
                                    // write the image as a PNG
                                    ImageIO.write(
                                            imageOutput,
                                            "png",
                                            new File("CapturedImage.png"));
                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    } );
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menu.add(screenshot);
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.add(menu);
            f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
 }
}
```

Comment: I want output with complete GUI, not only content of JFrame. It should have border, title bar and all. I am little suspicious on using Robot.createScreenCapture() method as it read screen pixel, and it solves above example but in case when I want to capture image by not interacting with current GUI and suppose there are other GUI windows on top of JFrame window GUI then captured image will not be only JFrame GUI, it will be just rectangle portion from screen no matter what showing at that moment.